# Which nvidia drivers version do I need?

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, cuda, nvidia

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I'm going to work with `cuda 11.3` and `torch 1.11` `python 3.8`

Which nvidia driver (version) do I need to install ?
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the latest version and you will be ok:

https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx